# DateObject was not the same as it in the ReplaceAll

Tags: replacement

When I use `ReplaceAll` to replace date objects, I find there will be an error which wouldn't appear when not in the `ReplaceAll` enviroment. For example:

```
In[257]:= z1 = 
 DateObject[{2008, 4, 27, 9, 0, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 8.]

Out[257]= DateObject[{2008, 4, 27, 9, 0, 
  0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 8.]

In[258]:= z1[[1]]

Out[258]= {2008, 4, 27, 9, 0, 0.}

In[259]:= {5, z1, 6, 7} /. zz_?DateObjectQ -> zz[[1]][[4]]

During evaluation of In[259]:= Part::partd: Part specification zz[[1]] is longer than depth of object.

During evaluation of In[259]:= Part::partw: Part 4 of zz[[1]] does not exist.

Out[259]= {5, 9, 6, 7}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [RuleDelayed](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html) to avoid error messages

```
{5, z1, 6, 7} /. zz_?DateObjectQ :> zz[[1]][[4]]
```

RuleDelayed localises `zz` and prevents its attempted evaluation on the RHS of the rule.  "RuleDelayed has the attribute HoldRest." - docs.

Without RuleDelayed you are effectively trying to evaluate

```
zz[[1]][[4]]
```

> Part::partd: Part specification zz[[1]] is longer than depth of object.

etc.

Comment: Why should use `RuleDelayed` here? I don't understand.

Comment: `zz` is an date object, so `zz[[1]][[4]]` should be right? I still don't know need `RuleDelay`.

Comment: `z1` is a date object.  When you get to the rule `zz_ -> zz[[1]][[4]]` the last part: `zz[[1]][[4]]` is evaluated before the rule is applied.  Use RuleDelayed, which has attribute [HoldFirst](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldFirst.html) to hold evaluation of `zz[[1]][[4]]` until after the rule is applied.

Comment: Before the rule is applied, why evaluating of `zz[[1]][[4]]` will cause error?

Comment: because `zz` is just a symbol at that stage, not a date object.

Comment: I know now. But, how did you know these processes?

Comment: I learned this on StackOverflow.  When you have symbols both sides of a rule it is advisable to use RuleDelayed to localise the variable, e.g. `a_ :> a^2`.  Rule is ok in cases like `a_ -> 1`.

Comment: After you told me the process of the rule, I know now. But, how did you know these?

Comment: One learns a lot on Mathematica StackExchange!  Very useful

Comment: Yes. Thank you for your patient explanation!